# Create my own boot.img for rooting?

Tags: rooting

Among the files needed to root an Android device (such as superuser.apk and su), an unsecured boot image is also required (boot.img) to allow for the installation of the superuser and su.

I understand the theory behind the unsecured boot image (ro.secure=0 set in the ramdisk) - is it possible for me to make this file myself? Or at the least, where can I download it independently of the zip packages that it usually comes with? I'd prefer to create it myself or download the file from the source rather than rely on zipped packages (for version tracking and change logs).

Thanks!

Comment: Hey mate I think this is what we're both looking for.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775 And here mate:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qRR2vseX4E

Answer (score 3):

You generally don't need to edit the boot.img to root your phone.
What's your phone model, so we can give you the instructions?

Edit: To root a Galaxy Nexus, first you have to unlock the bootloader, which is really easy since the GNex is a dev phone, just google how to unlock the bootloader, and follow the instructions. I recommend [droid-lifes tutorial](http://www.droid-life.com/2011/12/05/how-to-unlock-the-galaxy-nexus-bootloader/), but anyone should do. Then all that's left is the rooting.

- First you have to download [this zip file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15110285/FYA%20Files/GNexus-root-package-FYA.zip)
- Then unzip the file anywhere on you computer, like C:\gnex\
- Install the Samsung drivers that are in the zip
- After you have installed the drivers, turn the phone of and connect the USB to your computer and phone.
- Open a command prompt from the start menu, then move to the directory you unzipped the file to (e.x. cd C:\gnex)
- Now you have to boot your phone into fastboot mode, by pressing and holding both the volume-UP and volume-DOWN buttons and then press the power button.
- Next, type `fastboot devices` into the command prompt you opened earlier, and check that your phone is in the list.
- Now we have to soft-boot an insecure boot image by typing `fastboot boot boot.img` into the command prompt
- When the phone has rebooted, open settings, and go to `Settings -> Applications -> Development` and check in the `USB debbuging` option.
- Now execute all of these following commands, after each other, in the command prompt:

  1. adb root
  2. adb remount
  3. adb push su /system/bin
  4. adb push Superuser.apk /system/app
  5. adb shell chmod 06755 /system/bin/su
  6. adb shell chmod 06755 /system/app/Superuser.apk
- Now your device should be rooted and ready.

Comment: I'm using a Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: @kaspnord try that, if there's something you don't understand, or that doesn't work, email me at demizide@gmail.com, and I'll try my best to help you.

Comment: I know how to root my device, but thanks for the taking the time to write them out. My question pertains specifically to the creation of the unsecured boot.img file needed for the rooting process.

Comment: you *don't* need to create an unsecure boot.img to root, you just need to unlock the bootloader, as i sais in my answer.

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but I would also like to get the "secured" `boot.img` file directly from the stock phone so that I can go through the exercise of "unsecuring" it myself (changing to ro.secure=0) and booting with that one. I want to do this instead of using a `boot.img` that I download from the net that is part of someone else's root package. Thanks!